# vsftpd will not accept passwords encrypted with MD5

Tags: ftp, pam, vsftpd, md5

I am setting up an server with vsftpd to let virtual users access their space. Now it is fully working but only with CRYPT passwords.  So

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd phpmyadmin
```

will not allow me to log in, but

```
sudo htpasswd -c -d /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd phpmyadmin
```

will.

/etc/vsftpd.conf

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
nopriv_user=vsftpd
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www/vhosts/$USER.universe.local
chroot_local_user=YES
hide_ids=YES
guest_username=vsftpd
```

/etc/pam.d/vsftpd

```
auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd crypt=2
account required pam_permit.so crypt=2
```

I installed apache2.4.3 from source as well as PHP.

Things I've tried:

- Google a lot
- Set crypt=2
- ask friends
- use SHA (doesn't work either)
- update htpasswd and vsftpd

I have been struggeling with this for a week now, I hope u guys can help me further

Comment: Which OS are you using ? On Linux the supposed default is crypt which is the same as using -d.

Comment: for the sake of completeness, `-m` will generate MD5-based apache-style hashes (`$apr1$salt$hash`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`htpasswd` generates MD5 hashes in the Apache format, which you can verify by seeing that they start with `$apr1$`, but PAM only supports formats that your platform's implementation of `crypt(3)` implements. For Glibc, the equivalent (MD5-based) would be `$1$`. You just need to generate the passwords with a different tool. Here's an example:

```
sh$ openssl passwd -1
Password: 
Verifying - Password: 
$1$vhzHvIYn$2Ro.R0WdLnxrWjHcs5RbA/
```

You can copy this hash into your `ftpd.passwd` file in the `username:hash` format, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this! It worked! can i make pam support apache's md5 version?

Comment: Looking at the pam_pwdfile code, it looks like you'd have to write the support in and recompile. It even contains an entire implementation of the `$1$` MD5 password hash, all the way down to the MD5 primitive, so it's not fully `crypt`-aware.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on @bonsaiviking's answer you can generate the openssl md5 password and add it to the ftpd.passwd file in one line using htpasswd's batch mode -b, and plaintext -p options as follows:

```
htpasswd -c -p -b ftpd.passwd *username* $(openssl passwd -1 -noverify *password*)
```

The example above (Ubuntu) also creates a new ftpd.passwd file if it doesn't exist using -c

Comment: htpasswd outputs: "Warning: storing passwords as plain text might just not work on this platform." I guess that's because it *thinks* that it's indeed a plan text one but in fact it's the hash generated by the openssl. Using this approach to generate passwords worked with vsftp.

Comment: Right, htpasswd may generate that warning b/c your passing the MD5 hash as a plain text string.

Comment: Made script to do this based on this - grab here https://gist.github.com/bmatthewshea/53ed5148f09dfed50cebd10650ca551b

Answer (score 1):

The two commands that you show are equivalent because the `-d` option tells [htpasswd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/htpasswd) to use crypt which is the default for most operating systems.

If you want passwords hashed with md5 then you should use `-m`

```
sudo htpasswd -m /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.passwd test
New password:
Re-type new password:
Adding password for user test
grep test /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.passwd
test:$apr1$GTYtpKS1$Jyfgu42kDspxdJTPPzSOY.
```

Which shows that test's password has been encrypted using md5.

Comment: He must be using a different version of htpasswd, since he gets different results with and without `-d`.

Comment: As mentioned this DOES NOT work with vsftp - it generates apache style md5's. per above ^ http://serverfault.com/a/450220/92023